# Persistant casper-rw drive not booting

Tags: boot, partitioning, xubuntu, live-usb, persistence

Following a tutorial I attempted to create a casper-rw drive in ext4 to make space for my program s(In xubuntu). I used Unebootin to create a 4gb persistant file on my fat32 partition. The boot was fine and I used a spare copy of another distro to delete the 4gb persistant file to make room for the significantly larger partition. Does anybody have any idea what is going wrong here? Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult from your description to know what went wrong. It is possible to replace the file casper-rw with a partition with the label casper-rw and an ext file system (ext2, ext3 or ext4). I have done it manually, so I know that it works.

Maybe the easiest solution for you is to install ***mkusb*** and let it start from the beginning. It creates a **casper-rw partition** for persistence automatically.

You can decide how much of the available drive space to use for persistence. The rest (of the available drive space) will be used for a **usbdata** partition, available also from Windows.

See these links

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! Is mkusb a tool you can use from ubuntu or windows? If its ubuntu is it possible to use a live install to install it?

Comment: mkusb works in linux, so yes in Ubuntu, but not in Windows. And yes, it is possible to install mkusb into a live system (but without persistence it will disappear after reboot or shutdown). So you can use a two step method: Create a live (live-only) Ubuntu USB boot drive from Windows. Install mkusb into this live Ubuntu. Create a persistent live Ubuntu USB boot drive in another pendrive.

Comment: Self-extracting image file: The intention with **9W-DUS_i686.exe** is to provide a quick method to get a very small portable linux system with the tool dus (alias mkusb-dus alias guidus), that can create persistent live systems in Ubuntu and Debian and systems developed from them. It can also be used for other system tasks and can be a first step from Windows.  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/compressed-image_2_USB-or-SD#Self-extracting_image_file